# Excel column dependencies

Tags: excel, calculated-columns

I have a worksheet in Excel 2013.

```
  A               B                   C   D   E   F   G   H
1 Puzzle Number   Given Difficulty    n   b   g   c   a   nbg   
2 1               Very Easy           4   6   3   9   2   <problem cell>
3 2               Very Easy           .   .   .   .   .   <problem cell>
```

I want to generally set the value in column H to be, say, the values of the columns `C * D * E` in all rows that have values for `C`, `D`, and `E`.

I'm not sure if this is possible in Excel. If it isn't, is there some formula I can just copy and paste into each row of `H`?

I'm really not trying to use VBA, just Excel formulas. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It's not entirely clear (to me, at least) what you are asking. Your example shows `nbg` in `H1`, which is a concatenation of cells `C1:E1`, but your question implies that you want to multiply them together. `<problem cell>` in `H2:H3` implies that the numeric values in `C2:E2` and the "missing" values in `C3:E3` are problematic in some way. These factors can be accounted for, but it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: It seems like he wants to multiply them together, but isn't sure if that can be done in Excel. I think it's "problematic" due to ignorance of Excel ("I'm not sure if this is possible in Excel. If it isn't, is there some formula I can just copy..."). The concatenation probably shouldn't be taken literally here.

Comment: D'oh... Maybe row 1 contains column names rather than values. Sorry, I think I was confused by the fact that both Excel column letters and named columns were provided. Still, it is worth clarifying what the desired behavior with cells that are 0 or blank is...

Comment: @Brendan nbg in math means n * b * g. And yes, row 1 is a title row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a [formula](http://www.excel-easy.com/introduction/formulas-functions.html), which are an important feature of Excel.

```
=if(or(c2="",d2="",e2=""),"",c2*d2*e2)
```

Put that in H2, and then [drag down](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db).

This says that if either C2, D2, or E2 are blank, show nothing, otherwise, multiply the three together.

By dragging down (or ctrl-d), you copy the cell, changing c2 to c3 (and so on) for each row.

Comment: And.in the last slot, I can pretty much do any equation?

Comment: You can put any equation in any cell, and it will evaluate (as long as your syntax is correct). The first link is a beginner's guide. They're extremely useful to learn :)